# Converting Crystal Reports to DevExpress reports

Tags: crystal-reports, devexpress, report, reporting, xtrareport

I'm currently converting all of the Crystal Reports we have at work to DevExpress Reports. However, I haven't been able to find the DevExpress equivalent of CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Section.  What would the correct class be?  I am using DevExpress v 16.2

Answer (score 1):

You actually have something similar in xtraReports, named [Report Bands](https://documentation.devexpress.com/XtraReports/2590/Fundamental-Concepts/Understanding-Report-Bands) as you can see in the image below

[image]